# CSRF using cookie as auth method

Tags: javascript, php, security, authentication, cookies

I don't see any wrong using cookie auth, the limitation is for mobile apps, where they aren't browser, won't send cookie back to the server.

I took this statement from somewhere

> The browser automatically sending cookies also has a big downside,
>   which is CSRF attacks. In a CSRF attack, a malicious website takes
>   advantage of the fact that your browser will automatically attach
>   authentication cookies to requests to that domain and tricks your
>   browser into executing a request.
>
> Suppose the web site at https://www.example.com allows authenticated
>   users to change their passwords by POST-ing the new password to
>   https://www.example.com/changepassword without requiring the username
>   or old password to be posted.
>
> If you are still logged in to that website when you visit a malicious
>   website which loads a page in your browser that triggers a POST to
>   that address, your browser will faithfully attach the authentication
>   cookies, allowing the attacker to change your password.

Is that even an issue? If I don't do allow_header(*) then different domain can't send any http request to do anythign at all, so why people are saying cookie based auth is not secured?

Comment: CORS is a relatively new, it can be turned off, cookies not set as HTTP only, storing secrets in the cookie, not using HTTPS etc etc.. security depends entirely on how you implement many layers both sides including the server. who implements a change password without checking the user or adding CSRF lol.. Also dont use cookies, use jwt which could include your csrf token..

Comment: @LawrenceCherone it's a poor excuse to blame cookie auth if the developer don't check for user to change password lol

Comment: Your right, cookies are for state, not security.